# How do I hash hundreds of files by iterating through them using a while loop in Linux and print the output in a .txt file?

Tags: linux

I have a folder which contains many files. I'd like to generate the md5 hash value for each file using a while loop in the ubuntu terminal window.

I tried using this loop. `while read -r line; do (echo $line); done < output.txt`

Now I'm not sure how to pipe the md5 command into this loop to get the hash values.
I did some research and I couldn't find anything. However i found some for DOS.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Show your workings.

Comment: Edit your question to show your working and research, please don't use the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want **all** files in a folder (or a globable pattern) just run

```
md5sum /path/to/folder/*
```

If you do need to read the file names from a text file, try

```
while read -r fn; do md5sum "$fn" ; done <filenames.txt >md5sums.txt
```